# MongoDB using an array of IDs from one Collection to filter the results based on the IDs from another Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose there is a MongoDB Collection `CollA`. Say `CollA` has the following three Documents:

```json
{"_id": "1", "name": "Bob"},
{"_id": "2", "name": "John"},
{"_id": "3", "name": "Will"}
```

Let's say there is another MongoDB Collection `CollB` which has the following Document:

```json
{
    "_id": "1", 
    "foo": {
        "arr": ["1", "3"]
    }
}
```

Is there a way in MongoDB to query `CollB` for the `foo.arr` array contents (`["1"],["3"]`) and use it to retrieve the Documents in `CollA` which have these `_id` values, to produce the following result:

```json
{"_id": "1", "name": "Bob"},
{"_id": "3", "name": "Will"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a simple `$lookup` from `CollB`. Use `$replaceRoot` with the `$lookup` result after `$unwind`

```js
db.CollB.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "CollA",
      "localField": "foo.arr",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "collALookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$collALookup"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$collALookup"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XXOk4gPUCWy) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- lookup `_id` field with array `foo.arr` and limit 1, we just care if joined
  (no need to save many documents to memory)
- keep documents that joined (not empty results)
- unset the results field

*this will keep from collA all the documents that their `_id`, are in any array in collB (if you want only for 1 specific document of collB i think starting from collB like ray's answer makes more sense, but add a `$match` also before the `$lookup` for the 1 member of collB)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62c59806befa88fe45d75ec0)

```js
collA.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "collB",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "foo.arr",
    "pipeline": [{"$limit": 1}],
    "as": "results"}},
 {"$match": {"$expr": {"$ne": ["$results", []]}}},
 {"$unset": ["results"]}])
```